# Can't get mongoose virtual populate up and running in NestJS app

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-populate

I am currently working on a project where virtual populates are quite necessary:

There's a customer scheme, a document scheme as well as some others referencing the customer. Inside the customer I want to populate the referenced items.

I already had a working Model using Typegoose, which I had to remove from the project because of late incompatibilities. This is how it worked **before**:

```
  @prop({ 
    ref: () => DMSDocument,
    foreignField: 'linkedCustomers', // compare this value to the local document populate is called on
    localField: '_id', // compare this to the foreign document's value defined in "foreignField",
    justOne: false
  })
  public documents: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DMSDocument' }[];
```

Now I was trying to achieve this using **nestjs/mongoose** only after removing typegoose:

```
@Prop({ 
    virtual: 'documents',
    ref: 'DMSDocument',
    foreignField: 'linkedCustomers',
    localField: '_id',
  })
  public documents: DMSDocument[];
```

Virtual getters working just fine since I'm just using

```
@Schema({ toJSON: { virtuals: true, getters: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true, getters: true }})
```

The model ist populated like this:

```
this.customerModel.findOne(params)
.populate('documents', '', 'DMSDocument')
.populate('repairs', '', 'Repair')
```

I am somehow stuck - I just get empty arrays, no errors. What Am I missing? Are they even possible using nestjs/mongoose?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I managed to get things working again, but not in a preferred way:

After defining the class and converting it to a schema via

```
export const CustomerSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Customer);
```

I just had to "manually" add the virtual populates:

```
CustomerSchema.virtual('documents', {
  ref: 'DMSDocument',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'links.customers',
  justOne: false
});
```

Everything is working as expected, but I'd prefer a way using the decorators.

Comment: `justOne` is set by default to `false`, so you don't really need to declare it.